# Daemon vs worker and when to use what?

Tags: multithreading, linux, operating-systems, multiprocessing

(Note that, below, I am frequently using term "*daemon or worker*" just to indicate that I dont know which word to use as I dont know the exact difference between them in the context explained below.)

Consider following scenarios:

1. I need to write a server listening on some port, which accepts a request on that port and fork a new *daemon or worker* for each of incoming requests to handle them.
2. I need to write a server which starts some pre determined number of *daemons or workers*, then listens on some port, and finally it assigns incoming requests on that port to one of currently free *daemons or workers*. This approach pre-creates pre-determined number of *daemons or workers* just to avoid spawning huge numbers of them if I get huge number of requests, which might be the case in first scenario.

I am doing this in linux using python. I have came across two approaches to create *daemon or worker*:

1. By using [`multiprocessing.Process`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) and setting its [`daemon`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.daemon) to `True`. When I tried this and observed the daemons or workers in the `ps` command output, I realized that *daemons or workers* dont have `PPID=1` (the `initd` process in linux), but their `PPID` is set to the PID (here `28822`) of server. Notice that this approach also leaves those *daemons and workers* in defunct state and they dont get removed from `ps` command output automatically. I have to explicitly kill them.

   ```
   $ ps axo pid,ppid,pgid,sess,comm --forest | grep -E 'python| PID'
      PID   PPID   PGID   SESS COMMAND
    28822  25898  28822  25898  |           \_ python3
    28823  28822  28822  25898  |           |   \_ python3 <defunct>
    28828  28822  28822  25898  |           |   \_ python3 <defunct>
    28831  28822  28822  25898  |           |   \_ python3 <defunct>
   ```
2. However when I do double forking using `os.fork()` <sup>[1](https://franklingu.github.io/programming/2016/03/01/creating-daemon-process-python-example-explanation/),[2](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/#correct-daemon-behaviour)</sup> and [handle `singnal.SIGCHLD`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24638179/1317018), it does not leave defunct processes and correctly assigns PPIDs of those daemons to 1. For example, following the output of `ps` command:

   ```
   $ ps axo pid,ppid,pgid,sess,comm --forest | grep -E 'python| PID'
      PID   PPID   PGID   SESS COMMAND
    43680  43300  43680  43300  |           \_ python3
    43683      1  43682  43682 python3
    43690      1  43689  43689 python3
    43699      1  43698  43698 python3
   ```

   Those three python processes with PIDs {43683,43690,43699} are *daemons or workers*, then have `PPID=1` and they disappear from command output once they execute fully.

**Doubts**

1. I believe the processes with `PPID=1` as created by double forking are actual unix daemons. Also, notice the [multiprocessing doc says following](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?#multiprocessing.Process.daemon):

   > Additionally, these are not Unix daemons or services, they are normal processes that will be terminated (and not joined) if non-daemonic processes have exited.

   So, I feel the processes created by double forking are real linux daemons while the processes created by multiprocessing library are just workers, even though the library calls them daemons.

   Am I right with this?
2. I want to know which approach will be suitable for above scenarios. I feel scenario 1 should be better implemented with multiprocessing approach, while scenario 2 should be better implemented with double forking approach.

   Am I right with this?